# ggplot legend remove values

Tags: r, ggplot2

For changing the text size on the y-axis of the following heatmap in ggplot the code below `theme` works fine, but if I also need to remove some of the axis labels for example showing only one for every three of them (in the following plot I need to show  "Ej3", "Ej6" and "Ej9" for example) how could only those labels be shown?[image]

My data:

```
"people","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
"Ej1",0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0
"Ej2",0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0
"Ej3",0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
"Ej4",0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1
"Ej5",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
"Ej6",1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
"Ej7",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1
"Ej8",0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
"Ej9",1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

Code so far:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
data <- read.csv("fruits2.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",")
data$people <- factor(data$people,levels=rev(data$people))
data.m = melt(data)
#data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
data.m[,"rescale"]<-rescale(data.m[,"value"],to=c(0,1))
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))

p
```

Comment: Doe you want to have the whole plot restricted to those cases or do you just want fewer labels printed on the y axis?

Comment: I just want fewer labels printed on the y axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to define new labels and leave those blank that you want to eliminate:

```
fewer.labels <- c("Ej9","","","Ej6","","","Ej3","","")
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
     scale_y_discrete(labels=fewer.labels) +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))

p
```

[image]